# Use vuejs3 and openid-client with webpack5

Tags: npm, vuejs3, openid, webpack-5

I test vue3 with the openid-client library by following these steps:

**Project creation**

```
npm install -g @vue/cli
vue create vue-openid-app
cd vue-openid-app
npm install openid-client
```

**Editing the Helloword.vue component for login feature**

```
<template>
  <div class="login">
      <button class="login-button" @click="login">Login</button>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import { Issuer, generators } from 'openid-client';

export default {
methods: {
  async login() {
    try {
      const issuerUrl = `https://oauth.domain/`;

      // Discover the OpenID provider configuration
      const issuer = await Issuer.discover(issuerUrl);

      // Create a client instance with the provider metadata
      const client = new issuer.Client({
        client_id: 'CODEID1234567890'
      });

      // Generate and store a unique state value for CSRF protection
      const state = generators.state();

      // Generate the authorization URL and redirect the user
      const authorizationUrl = client.authorizationUrl({
        scope: 'openid profile',
        response_type: 'code',
        state,
      });

      // Redirect the user to the authorization URL
      window.location.href = authorizationUrl;
    } catch (error) {
      console.error('Error occurred during login:', error);
    }
  },
},
};
</script>
```

**Webpack configuration for polyfill management**

```
npm install node-polyfill-webpack-plugin
```

with vue.config.js

```
const { defineConfig } = require('@vue/cli-service')
const NodePolyfillPlugin = require('node-polyfill-webpack-plugin');

module.exports = defineConfig({
  transpileDependencies: true,
  configureWebpack: {
    plugins: [
      new NodePolyfillPlugin()
    ]
  },
})
```

When I run the server and click on the login button, I've got an error

```
npm run serve
```

Like dependency problem

```
TypeError: URL is not a constructor
    at Issuer.request (webpack-internal:///./node_modules/openid-client/lib/helpers/request.js:60:11)
```

Comment: This issue doesn't happen to me with npm v8.19.2 and node v18.12.1. Try to update your node.

Comment: No change with node 18.12.1 and npm 8.19.2. Always the same error.

Comment: After updating the version, try to re-create the project. Or you could remove the node_modules, clean the node cache and re-install the modules.